# Reading data from file into queue in c++

Tags: c++, file, input, queue

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my input data into my queue...  I am so close to getting this to work right.

I know I am just confused about how things are working.  I have used example code and my instructions to come up with a working program that appears to be working correctly (other than not actually putting my input file data into the queue).  I bypassed the function I was trying to make for this.  In addition to this, I was trying to write a function to remove an employee from the queue (which I think does work), but I am not sure I was able to get it right...

I have not taken a programming class for over 10 years and really would love to get any help in understanding what I am doing and getting that darn data into the queue.

Below is my main driver file.  I will provide my header file code if needed.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this.

```
//Program Assignment #3 
//Creates Queue as a Linked Structure

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include"Employee.h"
#include"LinkedQ.h"

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    LinkedQ nodeQ;
    Employee EmpNumber;
    Employee LastName;
    Employee FirstName;
    Employee ServiceYears;
};
void loadFile(LinkedQ &);
void addEmp(LinkedQ &);
void delEmp(LinkedQ &);

int main()
{
LinkedQ empList;
int choice;

int numIn, yearsIn;
string LastName;
string FirstName;
LinkedQ empIn;
ifstream input;

input.open("Employee.txt");

while (input)
{
    input >> numIn >> LastName >> FirstName >> yearsIn;
    if (input)
    {
        cout << "this is where we load data from the file into the queue\n";
        system("pause");
        //empIn.Enqueue(numIn, LastName, FirstName, yearsIn);
        //empList.addEmp(empIn);
    }
}

input.close();

do
{
    //display menu
    system("cls");
    cout << "\t\tMenu: \n" 
        << "\t1. Add Employee\n"
        << "\t2. Remove Employee\n" 
        << "\t3. Count of Employees\n" 
        << "\t4. Quit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice and press return: ";

    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        addEmp(empList); // call to function to add an employee to the queue
        break;

    case 2:
        delEmp(empList); // call to fucntion to remove an employee from the queue
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << endl << "Count of Employees: "
            << empList.GetLength() << endl;    // See how many employees are in the queue
        system("pause");
        break;

    case 4:
        cout << "End of Program";           // End Program
        break;

    default:                                
        cout << "Not a valid choice!" << endl;
        cout << "Choose Again.";                    // Handling incorrect inputs
        system("pause");
        break;
    }
} while (choice != 4);      // If choice is not 4, continue running program

return 0;
}

//***********************************
//Loads the file (having trouble figuring out how to implement this part)
//***********************************
void loadFile(Employee &empList)
{
int numIn, yearsIn;
string LastName;
string FirstName;
LinkedQ empIn;
ifstream input;

input.open("Employee.txt");

while (input)
{
    input >> numIn >> LastName >> FirstName >> yearsIn;
    if (input)
    {
        cout << "this is where we load data from the file into the queue";
        //empIn.setFields(numIn, LastName, FirstName, yearsIn);
        //empList.addEmp(empIn);
    }
}

input.close();
}

//***************************************
//add an employee
//***************************************
void addEmp(LinkedQ &empList)
{
Employee newEmp;

newEmp.user();

empList.Enqueue(newEmp);
}

//****************************************
//remove a employee
//****************************************
void delEmp(LinkedQ &empList)
{
Employee EmpToRemove;
int empNum;
//  bool successful;

cout << "Please enter EMPLOYEE NUMBER of employee to remove:";
cin >> empNum;

EmpToRemove.setEmpNumber(empNum);

empList.Dequeue(EmpToRemove);

//successful = empList.Dequeue(EmpToRemove);

//if (successful == true)
//{
    cout << "Removed" << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
//}
//else
//{
//  cout << "Emp Not found" << endl << endl;
//}

}
```

Here is the LinkedQ implementation file:

```
//LinkedQ class

#include "LinkedQ.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>

struct NodeType
{
Employee info;
NodeType* next;
};

LinkedQ::LinkedQ(void)
{
newNode = nullptr;
front = NULL;
rear = NULL;
length = 0;
}

void LinkedQ::MakeEmpty()
{
NodeType* tempPtr;

while (front != NULL)
{
    tempPtr = front;
    front = front->next;
    delete tempPtr;
}

rear = NULL;
}

LinkedQ::~LinkedQ(void)
{
MakeEmpty();
}

bool LinkedQ::IsFull() const
{
NodeType* location;
try
{
    location = new NodeType;
    delete location;
    return false;
}
catch (std::bad_alloc exception)
{
    return true;
}
}

bool LinkedQ::IsEmpty() const
{
return (front == NULL);
}

void LinkedQ::Enqueue(Employee newItem)
{
if (IsFull())
    cout << "Queue is Full";
//  throw FullQueue();
else
{
    NodeType* newNode;

    newNode = new NodeType;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (rear == NULL)
    {
        front = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = newNode;
    }
    rear = newNode;
    length++;
}
}

void LinkedQ::Dequeue(Employee& item)
{
if (IsEmpty())
{
    //throw EmptyQueue();
    cout << "Queue is empty";
}
else
{
    NodeType* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = front;
    item = front->info;
    front = front->next;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        rear = NULL;
    }
    delete tempPtr;
    length--;
}
}

int LinkedQ::GetLength() const
{
return length;
}
```

And here is the Employee implementation file:

```
//employee Class

#include"Employee.h"

//Constructor
Employee::Employee()
{
EmpNum = 0;                                             
}

//setters

void Employee::setEmpNumber(int eNum)
{
EmpNum = eNum;
}

void Employee::setEmpName(string LName)
{
LastName = LName;
}

void Employee::setEmpFirstName(string FName)
{
FirstName = FName;
}

void Employee::setYearsService(int years)
{
YearsService = years;
}

void Employee::setFields(int num, string LN, string FN, int years)
{
EmpNum = num;
LastName = LN;
FirstName = FN;
YearsService = years;
}

void Employee::user()                                                 
{
string inputString;
int intNumber;

cout << "Employee Number ";
cin >> intNumber;
while (intNumber <= 0)                                                  
{
    cout << "Employee Number "; 
    cin >> intNumber;
}
EmpNum = intNumber;

cout << "Last Name: ";
cin >> inputString;
LastName = inputString;

cout << "First Name: ";
cin >> inputString;
FirstName = inputString;

cout << "Years of Service: ";
cin >> intNumber;
while (intNumber < 0)                                                   
{
    cout << "Years of Service ";
    cin >> intNumber;

}
cout << endl;
YearsService = intNumber;

}

//getters
const int Employee::getEmpNumber()
{
return EmpNum;
}

const string Employee::getLastName()
{
return LastName;
}

const string Employee::getFirstName()
{
return FirstName;
}

const int Employee::getYearsService()
{
return YearsService;
}

//overloads

bool Employee::operator == (const Employee &right)
{
bool status;
if ( EmpNum == right.EmpNum)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;
return status;
}

bool Employee::operator != (const Employee &right)
{
bool status;

if (EmpNum != right.EmpNum)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;
return status;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, it is important that you develop new functions *in isolation* as much as possible. Instead of trying to read a while file into a queue, try putting one hard-coded Employee into a queue, and then more than one. Independently, try reading one Employee from a file, then more than one. (Just print their names to show that the code is working correctly.) And before you post a question, try to reduce your code to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); it makes our job easier, and you may solve the problem while doing it.

Comment: Is there a particular flag that can be used for questions that don't provide a minimal, complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the parameter of `loadFile` should be of type `LinkedQ`, which, if I understand it correctly, is the queue class/struct, and the `empIn` variable should be of type `Employee`.

Edit:

The method you call on the `empList` object should be `Enqueue`, instead of `addEmp`.

Comment: That is actually how I originally had it coded, but it has a problem with this line:  empList.addEmp(empIn);  (LinkedQ has no member addEmp)

Comment: And indeed it doesn't!  lol!  Need to use the enqueue function that is a member of the LinkedQ class.  I should have seen this myself...lol.  Thanks!

Comment: I included that in my answer as well. You're welcome.

Comment: It would be a bit complicated to write specifically, but in short, you have to return a `bool` flag so that the commented out part will work, and you also need to find the item you actually need to delete, because now it invariably deletes the first item.

Comment: If you need more explanation, or more detailed answers, feel free to post that as a separate question.